# Value of .offset() is coming as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the below function

```js
function test(use) {
  var x = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  var y = x + jQuery(window).height();
  console.log(typeof(jQuery(use)));
  console.log(typeof(jQuery(use).offset()));
  var z = jQuery(use).offset().top;
  return ((y > z) && (z >= x - 100));
}
```

Now the issue is whenever this function is getting called, it gives me an error stating that cannot read property top() of undefined. So, the issue is in variable z. When I used `console.log()` statements for the 1st statement i.e. `console.log(typeof (jQuery(use)));`I get the value as object but for 2nd statement i.e. `console.log(typeof (jQuery(use).offset()));`
I get the value as undefined.

Thanks

Comment: A jQuery selector will always return an object, even if no element is found. Try `console.log(jQuery(use).length)`. If the output is `0`, it's because whatever the value of `use` is, is not a valid element or selector that's available in the DOM.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   You've provided *some* code (which is good) but it's not enough to determine the issue, which depends on the `use` variable.